# Error while runing the django project in web browser

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error when i run the django file in web browser. I created a django project named FirstBlog and started an app named blog. i also changed the view file, model file and url file and setting file

```
ImportError at /
No module named blog
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named blog
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in     
import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\George\\Documents\\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\\FirstBlog',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\lib',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Python27',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

***my views file is:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from blog.models import posts

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

***my urls is:***

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'FirstBlog.blog.views.home', name='home'),
```

pls help!!!

Comment: For all those people recommending changes to INSTALLED_APPS, that has **nothing at all** to do with allowing Django to find the code. INSTALLED_APPS controls whether the app is used for things like syncdb and foreign keys. It does not change the Python path at all.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py, you have tuple INSTALLED_APPS.

- So, enter your app_name 'blog' in INSTALLED_APPS.
- and change your url like this

  url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),

Answer (score 0):

i would like to know where the folder blog located. if you are placed it in FirstBlog/FirstBlog then try

settings.py INSTALLED_APP add

```
"FirstBlog.blog",
```

replace

```
from blog.models import posts
```

with

```
from FirstBlog.blog.models import posts
```

it is better to run django-admin.py startapp from Directory FirstBlog.(you might probably run from **FirstBlog/FirstBlog**)